# IIS 8.5 Credentials working for windows authentication but not for basic

Tags: iis, iis-8, basic-authentication, iis-8.5

I have to mention that I am new to IIS. I have a local IIS 8.5 on a windows server 2012 machine. When I enable the windows authentication (basic authentication is disabled), I can access and see the home page of IIS (http://localhost) with the credentials of a LDAP user in the same domain. However, when I enable basic authentication (windows authentication is disabled), I cannot access the home page with the same credentials I used for windows (The authentication pop up never goes away).

Shouldn't the same credentials work for both basic and windows authentication or basic authentication works differently ? If not, then how are the credentials validated in case of basic authentication ?

Note: Eventually I plan to write restlet java code to post resources using basic authentication.

Comment: What's the error code when clicking cancel in the prompt when basic authentication use enabled?

Comment: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: That's 401.3, not 401.1. You should focus on how to fix 401.3 error.

Comment: What I am getting is 401.1 (invalid credentials). 401.3 is permission denied. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780140(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I got this problem solved. For Basic Authentication (click on edit), we need to set the default domain (realm is optional). Once I set the default domain, I could login using the LDAP user credentials.